# Use IsAssignableTo with open generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, generic-interface

I'm trying to get all the interfaces (they are all open generic) derived from `IService` that a `Random` class implements. I'm sure that at least one interface `Random` is implementing inherits from `IService<,>` **but no items is being added to the `iServiceTypeInterfaces` list**.

I have the following code:

```
var iServiceTypeInterfaces = new List<Type>();
Type iServiceGeneric = typeof(IService<,>);
foreach(Type i of Random.GetInterfaces())
{
  Type currentGenericType = i.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
  bool isAssignable = currentGenericType.IsAssignableTo(iServiceGeneric);
  if(isAssignable)
  {
    iServiceTypeInterfaces.Add(i);
  }
}
```

```
public interface IService<T, TSearcheable>
  where T : class
  where TSearcheable : class
{
  Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAll(TSearcheable searchObj);

  Task<T> GetById(Guid id);

  Task Create(T entity);

  Task Update(T entity);

  Task Delete(T entity);
}
```

```
public interface IProjectService<T, TSearcheable> : IService<T, TSearcheable>
  where T : class
  where TSearcheable : class
{
  Task<List<Technology>> GetTechs(List<Guid> ids);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IsAssignableTo` isn't designed to return true for the open type `IProjectService<,>` and the open type `IService<,>`. After all, `IProjectService<T, U>` is not assignable to `IService<V, W>`, where `T`, `U`, `V`, `W` are any type. Yes, that is the question you are asking - you are not asking whether `IProjectService<T, U>` is assignable to `IService<T, U>` (which it is), because both types are open types! There's no information about their type arguments at all.

I'd recommend just writing out the logic you want using LINQ. From the interfaces of `Random`, you want the generic interfaces:

- whose generic definition is the same as `IService<,>`, or
- whose list of super interface contain a generic definition that is `IService<,>`

The LINQ is straightforward:

```
static List<Type> GetAllInterfacesAssignableTo(Type interfaceType, Type targetType) {
    var genericInterface = interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    return targetType.GetInterfaces()
        .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
        .Where(x =>
            x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericInterface ||
            x.GetInterfaces().Select(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition()).Contains(genericInterface)
        )
        .ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
GetAllInterfacesAssignableTo(typeof(Service<>), typeof(Random))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the afforementioned method `IsAssignableTo` and accesing all inherited interfaces from each one.

```
var iServiceTypeInterfaces = new List<Type>();
Type iServiceGeneric = typeof(IService<,>);
foreach(Type i of Random.GetInterfaces())
{
  IEnumerable<Type> inheritedInterfaces = i.GetInterfaces().Select(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
  bool inheritsFromIService = inheritedInterfaces.Contains(iServiceGeneric);
  bool isIService = i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == iServiceGeneric;
  if(inheritsFromIService || isIService)
  {
    iServiceTypeInterfaces.Add(i);
  }
}
```